# Simulation of a $ M/M/1/3$ queuing system (probability that it will become full in first $n$ time units).

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, simulation

I am trying to simulate the probability that an $M/M/1/3$ system will get full during its first n time units, meaning arrival and service times are exponential and here they are exp with mean $1.$

I also know that $X=0$ in the beginning.

My approach strategy is to just simulate say, $10000$ times and just use the amount of times that the system became full/(amount of repetitions).

Code:

```
                succ=0;
                sumsucc=1;
                X=0;
                reps=10000;

                for i =1:reps
                    T=0; %We start in the beginning, time is zero
                    X=0; %The queue starts out empty 
                    while T<=3 
                        if X==0 %if no customers, a customers arrives a exp(1) time later!
                            T=exprnd(1);
                            X=1;
                            continue %moves on to next iteration of loop
                        end
                        if X==1
                            rand1=exprnd(1);rand2=exprnd(1);
                            if rand1<rand2
                                X=0; T=T+rand1;
                            else
                                X=2; T=T+rand2;
                            end
                            continue
                        end
                        if X==2 %if there is 1 or 2 in system, competition between to random exp begins, rand 1 is service time, rand 2 is arrival time. First wins moves on to correpsonding place 
                            rand1=exprnd(1);rand2=exprnd(1);
                            if rand1<rand2
                                X=1; T=T+rand1;
                            else
                                X=3; T=T+rand2;
                            end

                            continue
                        end
                        if X==3 %if three, moves down and 1 successful event is added to "sumsucc"
                                sumsucc=sumsucc+1;
                                T=T+exprnd(1);
                                X=2;
                                break
                        end 
                    end
                end
     sumsucc/reps %should give me right answer.
```

Now, the expected answer is $0.268.$ 
Something is wrong.

Comment: Come on, please? Should I phrase myself differently?

Comment: The basic structure seems OK. Did you try truncating your code to see if it works for `M/M/1/2`? Essentially, you are asking us to do the tedious and uninspiring job of de-bugging your code to find a syntax or logic error. You might show your output, and the formula you used to get the correct answer. You might put the name of the programming language in your title to attract attention of the most sympathetic users. (I did not down-vote, not yet anyhow, but considered doing so.)